# AccessRestrictions AddIP for Multiple App Services in Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an Azure powershell script where the user has to add in the app service name, IP address and so on. I have 4 web apps where I would like to add the same IP address to. I would like to hard code the app service name so the user does not have to input it. How can I achieve this in powershell? Here is my code:

```
    Param
(
# Name of the resource group that contains the App Service.
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$RGName,

# Name of your Web or API App.
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$WebAppName,

# priority value.
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$priority,

# WhitelistIp values.
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
$IPList,

# rule to add.
[PSCustomObject]$rule


)
function Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule
{
$ApiVersions = Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceTypes |
Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq 'sites' |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ApiVersions

$LatestApiVersion = $ApiVersions[0]

$WebAppConfig = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' -ResourceName $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $RGName -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion

$WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions = $WebAppConfig.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions + @($rule) | 
Group-Object name | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Last 1 }

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $WebAppConfig.ResourceId -Properties $WebAppConfig.Properties -ApiVersion $LatestApiVersion -Force 
}
$IPList= @($IPList-split ",")
Write-Host "IPList found "$IPList"."
$increment = 1
foreach ($element in $IPList)
{
if ($element -eq "" -OR $element -eq " ") {continue}
else
{
$element=$element.Trim()
$rule = [PSCustomObject]@{
ipAddress = "$($element)/32"
action = "Allow"
priority = "$priority"
name = "WhitelistIP"+ $increment}
$increment++
Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -AppServiceName "$WebAppName" -rule $rule
}
}
$OutboundIP = @(Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name "$WebAppName" -ResourceGroupName "$RGName").possibleOutboundIPAddresses -split ","
$increment = 1
foreach ($element in $OutboundIP)
{
$rule = [PSCustomObject]@{
ipAddress = "$($element)/32"
action = "Allow"
priority = "$priority"
name = "OutboundIP"+ $increment}
$increment++
Add-AzureIpRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "$RGName" -AppServiceName "$WebAppName" -rule $rule
}
```

so my `$WebAppName` i want it to be hard coded, but I have 4 of these web-apps, how do I get this script to run 4 times with just having the user input his IP address once, all variables stay the same, just the `$WebAppName` should change to the hard coded values i give

Comment: Just a hint: consider posting [mcve] instead of full code, that might make things far more readable for people who want to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could something like the following (If I've correctly understood the problem).

```
$webAppNames = 'a,b,c,d'
$webAppList = $webAppNames.split(',')
Foreach($webAppName in $webAppList) { ....do stuff }
```